# How to get network type in dual sim in android

Tags: android

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 int networktype=mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
```

by using telephonymanager get sim one networktype.
how to get second sim networktype?

Comment: [getNetworkType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType()) says *the NETWORK_TYPE_xxxx for current data connection.* i.e. only for current active data connection.

Comment: @sivareddy, Did you get any solution for this?